# Submitting Swift 2 apps before the release XCode 7 ?

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect

Do you know if it's yet possible to submit some Swift 2 apps to Apple or will I need to wait for the official release of XCode 7 ?

Answer (score 1):

Swift 2 is supported only from xCode7, and xCode7 doesn't allow to ship apps to iTunes Connect so, actually, is impossible to submit app in Swift 2.

Comment: Actually XCode 7 should allow to upload to iTC since it's possible to send iOS 9 beta test flight distributions.